# How to analyze and visualize a 3D velocity field?

Tags: matlab, math, data-visualization, physics

I am trying to use the best practice techniques in the [Computational fluid dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics) area to analyze and visualize a [velocity field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field).

Given 6 arrays of moving particles' positions and velocities: `x,y,z` and `vx,vy,vz` respectively.

I want to visualize and calculate the induced velocity field and its properties such as: [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)), [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence), [isosurfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosurface) etc.

Here is a modest script of the [volume visualization](https://www.mathworks.com/videos/series/volume-visualization-98092.html) functions I was able to use without calling `meshgrid` (to avoid interpolation and more noise).

Ultimately, one of the things that I am not sure about is how to wisely create a mesh grid from my 50 points in space, the second is how to use CFD approaches to visualize the velocity field regardless the small amount of data points.

```
close all
rng default
t=0.1:0.1:10;
x = sin(t)'; 
y = cos(t)'; 
z = t.^0.2';
vx=y;vy=x;vz=z;

figure
subplot(2,3,1);
quiver3(x,y,z,vx,vy,vz);
hold on
streamribbon({ [x y z] }, {vx},{vy},{vz});

subplot(2,3,2);
[curl_val, cav] = curl([x,y,z],[vx,vy,vz]);  
surfc([x,y,z],cav);
subplot(2,3,3);
surfc([x,y,z],curl_val);

w = sqrt( vx.^2 + vy.^2 + vz.^2 );
subplot(2,3,4);
quiver3(x,y,z,vx,vy,vz);
streamtube({ [x y z] }, {w});

subplot(2,3,5);
quiver3(x,y,z,vx,vy,vz);

subplot(2,3,6);
surfc([x,y,z],[vx,vy,vz]);
```

[image]

When I run the above script (excluding the data generation) on a [real data](http://pastebin.com/raw/6Werdnpf), I get the following plots which aren't very informative:

[image]

Comment: Please try to keep your edits substantive. If you're making many minor edits on purpose to draw attention to your question, don't do that.

Comment: @Undo, I am doing the edits so I will get a high quality answer and to avoid low quality answers that don't address any of my core issues: how to plot the data, how to show vorticity, how to make the graph look good.

Comment: Can you please add the plot of your data, not just the ideal data. I think this will help the readers understand why the traditional plots break down

Comment: @bremen_matt thanks man. I appreciate that. Will do so

Comment: Also, for your data, you may want to include the first plot without the stream ribbon. The reason is that too few data points, along with noise in the data can make some of these traditional tools go bonkers. A lot of them are essentially approximating the gradient of a noisy signal, and when you do that, you amplify noise. By plotting the velocity field with quiver alone, it is easier for a human to see any underlying structure

Comment: @bremen_matt, done. Thank you for the comments. I think that the final reversion is much more comprehensive.

Comment: You say "I get the following plots which aren't very informative". But making nice figures is not the ultimate goal of CFD. What do you actually want to show, or, what is the question you are trying to answer? In my view, just plane 2D graphs obtained from full 3D data, are often much more informative than these complicated graphs.

Comment: @Bernhard I want to study the vorticity and relative velocities of each 2 particles

Answer (score 10):

I strongly suspect that the problem here is with the data, not the visualization technique. But in general, the problem is one or more of the following:

1) You do not have enough data to capture the underlying dynamics (the dynamics in space operate at a higher spatial frequency than you sampled)

2) The data is too noisy for the number of datapoints your collected.

3) The flow is fundamentally turbulent, and hence hoping for a nice laminar-like plot is not going to happen.

When you have problems visualizing data, the first rule of thumb is always to throw away any visualization that attempts to approximate a derivative (or gradient) in any way. The reason is that when you try to approximate a derivative with real data, noise almost always makes that estimate nonsense. For example, let's suppose we have a cosine that gets corrupted by some noise, and we try to numerically estimate the derivative from the data

```
figure
% Create a signal 
dt  = .1;
t = 0:.1:10;
x = cos(t);

% Add some noise 
y = x + .5 * randn(size(x));

% Compute the first order approximation of the derivatives of the signals 
dx = diff(x)/dt;
dy = diff(y)/dt;

% Plot everything
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,x,t,y)
axis tight
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t(2:end),dx,t(2:end),dy)
axis tight
```

[image]

In the first plot, which shows the raw data, the noise doesn't look to bad, but when we look at the derivative estimate! Ouch... The noise is really amplified. So forget about higher order properties of a flow, such as the curl and vorticity, which require gradients of the data.

So what can we do in cases like these? Well essentially, just look at the raw data. If there is a pattern, it will reveal itself. For instance, let's look at your raw velocity vectors from 3 different perspectives:

```
data = dlmread('data.csv','\s')
x = data(:,1);
y = data(:,2);
z = data(:,3);
vx = data(:,4);
vy = data(:,5);
vz = data(:,6);

close all
figure
subplot(1,3,1);
quiver3(x,y,z,vx,vy,vz);
view([1,0,0])
subplot(1,3,2);
quiver3(x,y,z,vx,vy,vz);
view([0,1,0])
subplot(1,3,3);
quiver3(x,y,z,vx,vy,vz);
view([0,0,1])
```

[image]

The only thing that looks even slightly structured is that last plot. However, that plot tells us that we probably also have turbulence (in addition to noise) to contend with.

Specifically, from view 3, it definitely seems like you are taking velocity measurements in a flow that is tightly hugging an object. In this case, your measurements are probably too tight though... and probably in the boundary layer. If that is the case (that the measurements are in the boundary layer), then you can get time-varying effects in the flow, meaning that it doesn't make sense to look at anything without also having a time component. The "nice" plots that you have in your answer are only really helpful when the flow is laminar, where we get to see these nice, consistent stream lines. If it is turbulent, then there is no discernable pattern in the flow, no matter how hard you look.

So in conclusion, I don't think you will be able to find a nice visualization for your data because either the sensors you used were too noisy, or the flow was too turbulent.

As an aside... consider what happens when we look at the raw velocity vectors from your "nice" dataset:

[image]

That, my friend, is a well-trained house pet. You have a wild mountain lion on your hands.

Comment: Thank you, could you please address the issue of the visualization?

Comment: In my opinion, the visualizations you are using are perfectly fine and valid. As proof, just look at the first set of plots you generated. So I am not sure what you are expecting on that front. My answer hopefully highlights the fact that the problem is not with the visualizations you are using, but with the data itself. If you have some particular aspect of the flow that you are trying to capture that is not captured by the plots, then please tell us

Comment: Please ignore the bad data, I have thousands of other data sets, stick to the perfect toy data. How do you visualize its vorticity, divergence, curl better? This post should be used by other people as well. Your noise explanation is good for people to understand how their data is noisy, but for the visualization part I would use the perfect trained pet as you named it. Thx

Comment: OK.  But you covered all of your bases here. Is there something in particular that you want to plot but don't know how? Or do you have some other example plots that you want to mimic? The one thing I will say is that when you see commercial plots,  they are almost always generated by cfd, and they use thousands of points, not 50 or 100. So if you think your plots are missing the quality of commercial ones, it can simply be that you do not have enough data points.

Comment: Also, generating a grid from your data points doesn't really make sense because you would essentially be asking how to interpolate over a small dataset. You can do that, but you have to know what the underlying dynamics are to do it well.

Comment: I agree that's why I asked this question

Comment: Just to clarify... are you generating the points from cfd or measuring the velocity in an actual flow?

Comment: Actual flow, but my question is about the optimal data, I like you noise analysis, though if you can add section of visualization it would be wonderful.